# Hide Group Panel Telerik DataGrid UWP

Tags: datagrid, uwp, telerik

I'm trying to hide the `GroupPanel` in the Telerik UI for UWP RadDataGrid control.

`radgrid.ShowGroupPanel` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

UserGroupMode="Enabled"  or UserGroupMode="Disabled" will show/hide the grouping panel.

@aghilpro  I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CanUserGroup`

`CanUserGroup (bool)` : Gets or sets a value indicating whether the user can group the data by tha values in the column using the built-in Grouping UI.

More info : http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/columns/datagrid-overview